# Using ng-repeat in mailto? (Send mail to multiple recipients by JSON properties)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mailto

I'm currently working on forms that uses angular, PHP and mySQL to track user entries. I've converted the SQL into regular JSON in this pen http://codepen.io/StuffieStephie/full/BzmxXd/ so you can see what I'm trying to do.

When I click the `Email All {{selected.field}} Volunteers` button, I'd like to have a comma separated list of all emails, that match the filter.

I can get a list by using

```
<b ng-repeat="d in names | filter:filters">{{d.email}}{{$last ? '' : ', '}}</b>
```

But how do I email those people? I feel like using `ng-href` is wrong here. A point in the right direction would be appreciated!

EDIT: Okay, I kinda figured out how to do it by setting the mail link as the text content of the list modal.  But this seems really wonky

`<a ng-href="mailto:{{emails}}" target="_blank" class="waves-effect waves-light btn margin-bottom-1em"><i class="material-icons left">email</i>Email All {{selected.field}} Volunteers ({{(names | filter:filters).length}})</a>`

```
  $scope.hasChanged = function() {
       $scope.filters = $scope.selected.field;
       $scope.emails = $( "b.theEmails" ).text();
    return $scope.emails;
  }
```

Also, I have to change the drop down filter to run the `hasChanged()` function so the value of `$scope.emails` will be assigned. (I tried to give it a value outside of the function but it doesn't seem to work. Any help?

Comment: As an option- you could add `ng-click="sendMail()"` instead of ng-href,  prepare mail in this function and use window.open with "mailto:"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! Angular is so fancy that sometimes I forget vanilla JS exists :P This could be more efficient but it works! Behold! http://codepen.io/StuffieStephie/full/QEaGPY/

```
// Lil function to check if empty
function isEmpty(obj) {
  if (obj) {
    for (var prop in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}


$scope.getEmails = function(){
  var statusFilter = $scope.filters;
  var res = [];
  for (var i=0;i<$scope.names.length;i++) {
       var thisVolunteer = $scope.names[i];
       var email = thisVolunteer["email"];
     if (isEmpty(statusFilter) == false){ //If there's a filter, status must match
         if ( thisVolunteer.status == statusFilter) {
             res.push(email); 
            } //END IF Matching Status
         }//END IF filter  

    // OTHERWISE (no filter) Add/push all emails into res array
    else {res.push(email); } //END ELSE add all
    } //END FOR 
  $scope.list = res.join(", "); //Join the emails as a comma separated list
}; //END GetEmails();
```

Init in HTML

```
<a ng-init="getEmails()" ng-href="mailto:{{list}}" target="_blank">
Email All {{selected.field}} Volunteers ({{(names | filter:filters).length}})</a>
```

And run the function again if the select dropdown has changed

```
  $scope.hasChanged = function() {
    $scope.filters = $scope.selected.field;   
    $scope.getEmails();
  }
```

Feeling pretty proud right now :D